# How can I get my low fee transaction to confirm?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

On May 3, 2023, I created a transaction with a very low fee.  The next day, I sent a similar transaction with a higher fee, and it quickly confirmed. As of today, 5/20/23, the first transaction still has 0 confirmations.  Can I get someone to mine this transaction with a higher fee?